# How can i get the image source from the other site?

Tags: php, arrays, web-scraping, output, preg-match-all

I had so many web site addresses which have images I want to have.
I want to know the image source at that web site.

Below is my php code. but that doesn't work.

```
  <?php
  $html = array('url1', 'url2', ...);
  $result = "";
  preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $html, $result);
  echo $result;
  ?>
```

Please, Would you complete above incomplete code?

Comment: how you expect that will be working with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better off with [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class , Never use **`Regex`** as a parser for parsing HTML Content.

```
$htmlsourceofthewebsite = file_get_contents('http://www.somewebsite.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlsourceofthewebsite);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $tag) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do i insert the website addresses i want to search?? I am a beginner, so sorry

Comment: <?php


$htmlsourceofthewebsite='http://www.w3schools.com';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlsourceofthewebsite);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $tag) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
}

?>

Comment: Nope , see the edited answer. Make use of `file_get_contents()`;

Comment: above code is right?? That doesnt work, either..

Answer (score 0):

You should not use regex to parse html content. Use DOMDocument.

Try like this:

```
$html=array('url1', 'url2', ........); // your url array

        foeach($html as $a){ //run a loop through your array
          getImage($a); // get images

        }

       function getImage($url){           
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($url);
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $t) {
                echo $t->getAttribute('src');
             }
          }   
       }
```

Document: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php